# Can I pause data stream by a flag with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

First of all, here is my code

```
viewModel.price
            .drive(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { (index: Int, Info, cell: Cell) in 
                 ....
          }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

viewModel.price's data type is **Driver<[Info]>**

In this code, I want to add a flag which is for pausing collectionView. 
When the flag from viewModel is "true" then keep drawing collectionView but if it's "false" then stop it.

I think I need to use **combineLatest** and **takeWhile** but not sure how to use this.

how can I use **combineLatest** and **takeWhile** for my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Driver.combineLatest(viewModel.price, viewModel.shouldDraw)
    .filter { $1 }
    .map { $0.0 }
    .drive(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { (index: Int, Info, cell: Cell) in 
             ....
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: That filter and map should be _in_ the view model.

Comment: @DanielT. you are right! I moved filter and map to viewModel :) Thank you!